# could someone explain this code( list of list in python)?

Tags: python, list

what I want to manipulate is the first element of v, the second print is supposed to be

```
[[3], [], [], [], []].
```

Code:

```
v = [[]] * 4

print(v)
v[0].append(3);  #what i want to manipulate is the first element of v 
print(v)
```

output:

```
[[], [], [], [], []]
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

Comment: i got it: 
v = [[] for n in range(4)]

Answer (score 0):

Python mutable variables (like `list`) are passed by reference.

```
v = [[]] * 4
```

Gives you a list of the same reference, so when you update one element of the list, all other moved with.

```
v = [[], [], [], []]
```

Will fix it

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer(I am waiting online).<br/>
but what if dynamic size like:
v = [[]] * N